# ember.js hasMany model relationship save

Tags: javascript, model, ember.js, ember-data

here is a summary of the current state of my app : https://gist.github.com/Daroth/6948372

The version of each framework :

```
Ember      : 1.0.0
Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.3
Handlebars : 1.0.0
jQuery     : 1.9.1
```

And my actual problem is on bookmark.save(); (l. 49).
As expected a POST request is send to /bookmarks path but request body is not what I excepted.

```
{
  "bookmark": {
    "link": "http://google.com",
    "title": "dsfsdf",
    "description": "qsdq",
    "date": null,
    "tags": [null, null]
  }
}
```

Is send but as you can see tags attribute is filled with an array of null values (one for each previously added tag).

I've try many things but none of them worked.

Comment: Are you sure that before calling bookmark.save(); bookmark has actually those values? you may try to console.log(bookmark); and check its values. Can you please provide your code in the jsfiddle provided (http://jsfiddle.net/jpUfA/). I've places all necessary libs, but even if it doesn't run please place inside your code.

Comment: Here is all my js code : http://jsfiddle.net/jpUfA/3/
I've placed a breakpoint on bookmark.get('tags').addObject(tag) line and i stops here one time for each tag as expected.

Comment: When do you set the date? where do you get the tag values from? is there a template? how do you call the create action?

Comment: Date is currently a read only attribute, defined server side when a bookmark is saved. Theire is templates, and I call the create action from a form submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`bookmark.get('tags').pushObject(tag)`

if nothing changes try to find all tags created in model after the loop,

```
console.log(store.findAll('tag'));
```

Comment: Sadly it does not work. I've try many other combination as well without any success at the end of the road.